# Inlined font-face reapplied by external

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have this problem with a web app. I was trying to avoid FOUT when critical CSS is enabled, so I have also inlined critical fonts in the head encoded in base64.

Everything is as I expected, however, I left the same font-face declarations in my asynchronous CSS, just NOT base64 encoded (just in case I do not inline my fonts in head) and when they are loaded, fonts are REAPPLIED and I see text disappearing and appearing again.

Does anyone know any solutions to this? Thanks

Comment: Missing codes pls

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have a font in a font-face block in a <style> element, followed by another font in a font-face block in a <link>, right? In that case, they have the same specificity and the second font-face won't be ignored. The solution, of course, is to remove the @font-face from the css file.

Comment: That is exactly correct. But isn't there any option without removing @font-faces from the css file?

Comment: Ehm, change the name of the font?